# Where can I find EVOC20 package for Emagic Logic 2.5?

Tags: software, audio, digital-audio

I know the vocoder was firstly developed by the company Emagic, which then bought by Apple. Now it is part of Logic Pro X and impossible to find the original version, that can work in Windows.

Does anyone still have a version of EVOC20 vocoder that was released in the 90s?